# ANTLR grammar matches incompatible rule instead of throwing NoViableAltException

Tags: c#, antlr, antlr3

I have the following ANTLR grammar that forms part of a larger expression parser:

```
grammar ProblemTest;

atom    :   constant
    |   propertyname;

constant:   (INT+ | BOOL | STRING | DATETIME);

propertyname
    :   IDENTIFIER  ('/' IDENTIFIER)*;

IDENTIFIER 
    :   ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')+;

INT 
    :   '0'..'9'+;

BOOL    :   ('true' | 'false');

DATETIME
    :   'datetime\'' '0'..'9'+ '-' '0'..'9'+ '-' + '0'..'9'+ 'T' '0'..'9'+ ':' '0'..'9'+ (':' '0'..'9'+ ('.' '0'..'9'+)*)* '\'';

STRING
    :  '\'' ( ESC_SEQ | ~('\\'|'\'') )* '\''
    ;

fragment
HEX_DIGIT : ('0'..'9'|'a'..'f'|'A'..'F') ;

fragment
ESC_SEQ
    :   '\\' ('b'|'t'|'n'|'f'|'r'|'\"'|'\''|'\\')
    |   UNICODE_ESC
    |   OCTAL_ESC
    ;

fragment
OCTAL_ESC
    :   '\\' ('0'..'3') ('0'..'7') ('0'..'7')
    |   '\\' ('0'..'7') ('0'..'7')
    |   '\\' ('0'..'7')
    ;

fragment
UNICODE_ESC
    :   '\\' 'u' HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT
    ;
```

If I invoke this in the interpreter from within ANTLR works with

```
'Hello\\World'
```

then this is getting interpreted as a *propertyname* instead of a *constant*. The same happens if I compile this in C# and run it in a test harness, so it is not a problem with the dodgy interpreter

I'm sure I am missing something really obvious... but why is this happening? It's clear there is a problem with the string matcher, but I would have thought at the very least that the fact that *IDENTIFIER* does not match the ' character would mean that this would throw a NoViableAltException instead of just falling through?

Comment: Not sure it has to do with it but your int rule is probably wrong. It should be like ('0'..'9')+. Also with the plus operator there you won't need another one in the constant rule.

Answer (score 1):

First, neither ANTLRWorks nor antlr-3.5-complete.jar can be used to generate code for the C# targets. They might produce files ending in .cs, and those files *might even compile*, but those files will not be the same as the files produced by the C# port of the ANTLR Tool (Antlr3.exe) or the recommended MSBuild integration. Make sure you are producing your generated parser by one of the [tested methods](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Antlr3CSharpReleases).

Second, `INT` will never be matched. Since `IDENTIFIER` appears before `INT` in the grammar, and all sequences `'0'..'9'+` match both `IDENTIFIER` and `INT`, the lexer will always take the first option which appears (`IDENTIFIER`).

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't spotted that. I am indeed using the C# port of the tool to generate my actual parser. Do you have any insights on the problem at hand?